# Alamofire post request return 404 in Swift

Tags: swift3, alamofire

I am going to post a request via alamofire. I can post request with Postman. Response return true (201 code). However when I am try with Alamofire returns 404 code. What's wrong?

My codes:

```
     let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "Authorization": "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "content-type": "application/json"
     ]
        let parameters:[String:Any] = [
        "xxx":123,
        "yyy":"test",
        "zzz":"iphone"
        ]

    Alamofire.request(myUrl, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response -> Void in

        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            print(response.response?.statusCode)

            break
        case .failure(let error):

            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Return this message :

```
success {
message = "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://xxxxx/PostErrorFeedBack'.";
```

}

Comment: It’s `Content-Type`, not `content-type`.

Comment: same, doesn't change anything

Comment: What URL are you trying to hit? Is it a public URL or are you trying to hit your own local server?

Comment: it does not seem 404, according to the message it was a successful request... where is exactly the 404 here?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one hope it may help you !!

```
let headers = [
    "Authorization": "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxx"
]
let parameters = [

]

Alamofire.request(.POST, "url", parameters: parameters, headers: headers, encoding: .JSON)
        .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
        .responseJSON { response in
            if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
                print("Success with JSON: \(response.result.value)")

               
            }
            else {
                let error = response.result.value as! NSDictionary
                let errorMessage = error.objectForKey("message") as! String
                print(errorMessage)
                failure(errorMessage)
            }


    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately didn't anything @Bikesh Thakur

Comment: I am getting this error 'Extra argument method in call'

Comment: I didn't understand in success updatedUser. What is it?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this method for using `Alamofire` as this worked for me.

```
let headers = [
               "Accept": "application/json",
               "Authorization" : "Authorization: Bearer ", //if any
               "Cookie" : "Cookie" //if any
              ]

let parameterDict: NSDictionary = NSDictionary.init(objects: [nameTextField.text!, reportTextView.text!], forKeys: ["Name" as NSCopying,"Message" as NSCopying])

Alamofire.request("API",method: .post, parameters: parameterDict as? [String : AnyObject] , encoding:JSONEncoding.default, headers:headers) .responseJSON {  response in switch response.result {

     case .success(let JSON):
         print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")
         let response = JSON as! NSDictionary

     case .failure(let error):
         print("Request failed with error: \(error)")


         }
    }
```